# Laravel factory user id always null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations, laravel-6

When trying to get a random user id in a factory, it always returns `null` despite the DB containing `50` users (created via the `User` factory).

```
'user_id' => User::all()->random()->id
```

I tried to display the retrieved resource doing this:

```
dd(User::all()->random())
```

and the result was quite consistent with what expected

> ```
> App\User^ {#num
>   #fillable: array:9 []
>   ...
>   #attributes: array:14 [
>     "id" => 25
>   ...
>   ]
> }
> ```

but this other method:

```
dd( User::all()->random()->id )
```

**always** returns `null`.

Comment: Did you tried like this? `dd((User::all()->random())->id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that using that method you are loading all the records in memory, then selecting one randomly to get your random object.

You could improve this querying one record in random order directly from the database:

```
$randomUser = User::inRandomOrder()->first();
```

Comment: Tried to assign the random user to a variable and then extracting the ID but it does not work. $randomUser = User::inRandomOrder()->first(); echo dd($randomUser->id);

Comment: Check your model. Maybe you have the `id` field included in your `$hidden` config. [Check this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json) for more info.

Comment: Okay I found the problem, I am using https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/encrypt-and-decrypt-help-code-example to encrypt the user email but apparently the *Encryptable* trait stops the whole model from working

Comment: I don't understand your question is different than your actual problem.